# Idenfifying a 10 digit number in middle of a string

Tags: c

I can have strings containing random 10 digit numbers e.g.
`"abcgfg1234567890gfggf"` or 
`"fgfghgh3215556890ddf"` etc

basically any combination of 10 digits plus chars together in a string, so I need check the string to determine if a 10 digit number is present. I use strspn but it returns 0

```
char str_in[] = "abcgfg1234567890gfggf";
char cset[] = "1234567890";    
int result;

result = strspn(str_in, cset);   // returns 0   need it to return 10
```

The fact that the following code returns 0 instead of 10 highlights the problem.  I asked this previously but most replies were for checking against a known 10 digit number. In my case the number will be random. Any better way than `strspn`?

Answer (score 3):

It returns 0 because there are no digits at the start of the string.

> The  strspn()  function calculates the length (in bytes) of the
> initial segment of s which consists entirely of bytes in accept.

You need to skip non-digits - `strcspn` - and then call `strspn` on the string + that offset. You could try:

```
/* Count chars to skip. */
skip = strcspn(str_in, cset);

/* Measure all-digit portion. */
length = strspn(str_in + skip, cset)
```

---

#### EDIT

I should mention this must be done in a loop. For example if your string is  `"abcd123abcd1234567890"` the first `strspn` will only match 3 characters and you need to look further.

Comment: Hi Everyone. Many thanks to all that answered. I tried a number of these solutions and this answer proved to be the best.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sscanf()`:

```
unsigned long long value;

const char *str_in = "abcgfg1234567890gfggf";
if(sscanf(str_in, "%*[^0-9]%uL", &value) == 1)
{
  if(value >= 1000000000ull)  /* Check that it's 10 digits. */
  {
   /* do magic here */
  }
}
```

The above assumes that `unsigned long long` is large enough to hold a 10-digit decimal numbers, in practice this means it assumes that's a 64-bit type.

The `%*[^0-9]` conversion specifier tells `sscanf()` to ignore a bunch of initial characters that are not (decimal) digits, then convert an unsigned long long (`%uL`) directly after that. The trailing characters are ignored.

Comment: `sscanf()` is potentially unsafe or even dangerous. I do **not** recommend using it.

Comment: @cyphar Huh? Any references to back that up? Of course you can shoot yourself in the foot with it, but that's the glory of C. My usage here should be safe.

Comment: @unwind `%llu` rather than `%uL`?

Comment: @unwind The "danger" of sscanf() is because of the potential for an attacker to give intentionally malformed input. Since `sscanf()` does several potentially bad practices (like trying to cast values to fit types, where the size of the types are majorly different), there is an implicit risk in using any of the scanf() family. Stack smashing and buffer overflows are the most common exploit using input, usually due to scanf(). While your usage is not implicitly unsafe, I would _not_ recommend using it simply on principle.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative use of `sscanf()`

(blatant variation of @unwind)

```
const char *str_in = "abcgfg0123456789gfggf";
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
// %*[^0-9]  Scan any non-digits.  Do not store result.
// %n        Store number of characters read so far.
// %*[0-9]   Scan digits.  Do not store result.
sscanf(str_in, "%*[^0-9]%n%*[0-9]%n", &n1, &n2);
if (n2 == 0) return 0;
return n2 - n1;
```

Counts leading `0` characters as part of digit count.

---

Should one wish to avoid `sscanf()`

```
char str_in[] = "abcgfg1234567890gfggf";
const char *p1 = str_in;
while (*p1 && !isdigit(*p1)) p1++;
const char *p2 = p1;
while (isdigit(*p2)) p2++;
result = p2 - p1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str_in[] = "abcgfg1234567890gfggf";
    int result = 0;
    const char *pattern = "[0-9]{10}";
    regex_t re;
    char msg[256];

    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
            perror("regcomp");
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = regexec(&re, str_in, (size_t)0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&re);

    if (!result) {
            printf("Regex got a match.\n");
    } else if (result == REG_NOMATCH) {
            printf("Regex got no match.\n");
    } else {
            regerror(result, &re, msg, sizeof(msg));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msg);
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strspn` seems handy for this, but you would have to include it in a loop and search several times. Given the specific requirements, the easiest way is probably to make your own custom function.

```
int find_digits (const char* str, int n);
/* Searches [str] for a sequence of [n] adjacent digits.
   Returns the index of the first valid substring containing such a sequence,
   otherwise returns -1.
*/


#include <ctype.h>  

int find_digits (const char* str, int n)
{
  int result = -1;
  int substr_len = 0;
  int i = 0;

  for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if(isdigit(str[i]))
    {
      substr_len++;
    }
    else
    {
      substr_len=0;
    }

    if(substr_len == n)
    {
      result = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

(I just hacked this down here and now, not tested, but you get the idea. This is most likely the fastest algorithm for the task, that is, if performance matters at all)

Comment: No - you are expecting devs to write actual code to do stuff - everyone knows that you must use only library functions, whether appropriate or not :)

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah a programmer shouldn't spend 5 minutes to write an utterly simple algorithm like this. Instead they should invoke the most ineffective library function they can find, preferably one with buffer overrun vulnerabilities and undefined behavior pitfalls. Bonus points if the library function call is completely unreadable and you have to look it up in a book to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

for testing a suit of "0123456789" inside a string you can do something like that:

```
int             main()
{
  char str_in[] = "abcgfg1234567890gfggf";
  char cset[] = "1234567890";
  int result;
  int i;
  int f;

  i = 0;
  f = 0;
  while (str_in[i])
    {
      if (str_in[i] == cset[f])
        {
          f++;
          if(f == strlen(cset))
            return (f);
        }
      else
        f = 0;
      i++;
    }
}
```